# How to get the user a webapplication will run under?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, deployment, web-deployment-project

Question: I have a web setup project.

It installs the webapp and puts it into the appropriate virtual directory.
So far so good.
My question now is: how do I set folder write permission?
My problem is, I can set the permissions programmatically, but I need to know the IIS user the application runs under, since it's that user that need the permissions. 

How can I get (or set) the IIS user ?

Comment: Security tab in IIS - if you have anonymous access enabled. Whatever user if you use impersonation. You can use `HttpContext.Current.User` to check what user is authenticated.

Comment: Yes, but I need to check it in the deployment project, not in the ASP.NET web application... permissions would be pretty pointless if you could give yourself those you don't have...

Answer (score 0):

The default value is usually `IUSR_%machinename%`

You could attempt to read the IIS metabase file but it's usually in a system folder (C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\metabase.xml).  Find the `<IIsWebService>` element with the proper `Location` attribute and then read the value of the `AnonymousUserName` attribute.  I don't recommend writing directly to the metabase.

I am only familiar with IIS6 so the above may vary by version.